# If jQuery has Class do this action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I am trying to check whether or not a particular element has been clicked but am having trouble doing so. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="my_special_id" class="switch switch-small has-switch" data-on="success" data-off="danger">
    <div class="switch-on switch-animate"><input type="checkbox" checked="" class="toggle">
        <span class="switch-left switch-small switch-success">ON</span>
        <label class="switch-small">&nbsp;</label>
        <span class="switch-right switch-small switch-danger">OFF</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_special_id').click(function() {
        if ($('#my_special_id div:first-child').hasClass('switch-on')) {
            window.alert('ON!');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I am guessing that my id "my_special_id" is not what is actually being clicked?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Is there more than one #my_special_id, or is that the only place you can possibly have a `switch-on`?

Comment: @Lochemage Sorry for the confusion. The #math_exam_active should not have been there when I posted my code. In my file, it was correct, just not above in my posting. I have updated my posting with the correct code.

Comment: it seems to do something here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wBjrR/1/ what is it supposed to do

Comment: @ArunPJohny When a user toggles the checkbox, I will do an Ajax request. But for testing purposes, I am trying to alert myself after checkbox is toggled.

Comment: The current code works well, try using border and you'll see the div is being clicked well, and his child has class http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/u7euj/

Comment: what type of toggle button you are using

Comment: @suhail I am using a Bootstrap plugin

Comment: @Edward I am using a Bootstrap plugin. Is this what could be causing it not to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for a alert when the checkbox is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_special_id input.toggle').click(function() {
        if ($('#my_special_id div:first-child').hasClass('switch-on')) {
            window.alert('ON!');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wBjrR/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess click event should have event parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_special_id').click(function(e) {
        if (e.target check condition) {
            window.alert('ON!');
        }
    });
});
```

parameter 'e' above specified is the event object that has all info about click event.
so if u check all info under 'e.tartget', u will be able to find out which one is clicked.
Hope it's helpful for you.
Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put alert when you click on that particular class `switch-on`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#my_special_id div:first-child .switch-on').on('click',function() {
                   window.alert('ON!');
          });
     });
</script>
```

Or even try like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_special_id').click(function() {
        if ($(this + 'div:first-child').hasClass('switch-on')) {
            window.alert('ON!');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The click event will trigger to whatever you're bound do. the only time you'd have to be worried is if you bound to both a parent and child (e.g. you had listed `#my_special_id,.switch-small`--then you'd have to look at `e.target`).

With that said, you can use scope to limit how jQuery finds the `div:first-child`. I'm not 100% sure what you're after, but the below appears to do what you're after:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_special_id').click(function() {
        // look for div:first-child within `this` (where `this=#my_special_id`
        // per the .click selector above)
        if ($('div:first-child',this).hasClass('switch-on')) {
            window.alert('ON!');
        }
    });
});
```

If you're looking to bind to the on/off separately, you may want to change it around a bit. we can still check for `.switch-on`, just have to traverse differently:

```
 // here we bind to the on/off buttons and not the container
$('#my_special_id .switch-small').click(function(){
  // you want the facsimilee of `div:first-child`, so (because we're now
  // within that node, we use .parent() to get back up to it
  var $firstChild = $(this).parent();
  if ($parent.hasClass('switch-on')){
     alert('ON!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_special_id').click(function() {
        if ($('#my_special_id div:first-child').hasClass('switch-on')) {
            alert("On!");
        }
    });
});
```

You are sure you have JQuery?

Your code looks fine I think either you have a syntax error somewhere else or you do not have JQuert.

does this alert?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Jquery works");
});
```

Comment: I tested your code to make sure jQuery was on and it was. I then tested your code you said was working but unfortunately it is not working for me.